# Azure DevOps Pipelines: how to check out branch of the self repo?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a yaml pipeline which I want to make it to run for more branches. Therefore I am trying to checkout one branch, specified in pipeline variables. I'm unable to do so, the error being `Unexpected value 'ref'`.

The pipeline file is:

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - 'release/dev'
      - 'release/test'
      - 'release/prod'
  paths:
    include:
    - '*'

resources:
- repo: self
  ref: $(branch)

variables:
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'conn'
  containerRegistry: 'conn.reg'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:  
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - template: docker-build-template.yml
      parameters:
        dockerfilePath: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile.release
        imageName: conn.reg/container
        imageRepository: container
        pushToRegistry: true
```

How can I checkout different branches for building the container out of them?

Later edit: I want the pipeline to automatically run after a PR or a commit is pushed on any of the braches. (Manually it can be run with specifiyng a branch.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Azure DevOps Pipelines: how to check out branch of the self repo?

You could specify the name of the self repo in the resource with a specific ref,like:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: MyTestProject 
    type: git
    name: MyTestProject
    ref: $(branch)
```

Then checkout with another path:

```
steps:
- checkout: MyTestProject
  path: Another path/xxxx/xxx
```

Comment: Where is this syntax $(branch) documented? All I have is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-repositories-repository?view=azure-pipelines where it says "ref: [..] Does not accept variables."

Comment: @Jepper actually as is right now "ref" supports templates (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-repositories-repository?view=azure-pipelines)

Comment: you can use it with expression: `ref: '$(branch)'` , those quotes are required.

Answer (score 0):

You don't define the `self` repo as a resource. If you want to run your build on another branch, just choose your branch in the "Run pipeline" screen:

[image]

As for running automatically after completing a PR, you already have the `triggers.branches.include` set, so merges (or pushes) to all these branches will trigger a build in which the relevant branch will be checked out.

Comment: That is if I do it manually. But if I want the build to automatically run after a PR is completed of any of the branches? I will edit the question with this detail.

Comment: What do you mean by "A PR is complete"? You mean merge? That's a CI trigger, and it will run on the branch you merge to...

Comment: A new commit in the branch, regardless of its type (merge, push, push -f, etc.). Yes, a CI trigger is what I am looking for, for different branches.

Comment: You already have it defined in the `triggers.branches.include` field

Comment: Does this mean I can take the current branch name to find out which one triggered the pipeline?

Comment: You have a variable set in your pipeline containing the branch name, refer to the "Use predefined variables" page of the docs

Comment: Yes, that is right. Can you make or edit your answer with this info to mark it as accepted?